# How to display the snippets in elastic search?

Tags: elasticsearch, position, offset, code-snippets

I was working on project to display the matching snippets with its exact locations in the respective document.  We are indexing PDF and HTML documents into elastic server. On searching for the text in the indexed documents, first we need to display text around matched text from the document. Then, on clicking this entry, we should bring the document and position at the exact location by highlighting the matched text.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

- CM

Answer (score 2):

You can use `highlight` for highlighting the matched text.

```
GET /index/type/_search
{
"query" : {
    "match_phrase" : {
        "field" : "some text"
    }
},
"highlight": {
    "fields" : {
        "field" : {}
    }
  }
}
```

You can refer [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/highlighting-intro.html).